# I would like to request that `answers:no` be interpreted to mean `answers:0`

Tags: feature-request, search

I often type `answers:0 closed:no` into the search bar.

Today, I typed `answers:no closed:no`

There are questions with 9 or more pre-existing answers in the search results.

My feature request is: Use some code to enable the [boolean operators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) so that `answers:no` is interpreted the same way as `answers:0`?

Similar to the `isanswered:` function, where yes/true/1 returns only questions that have at least one positively-scored answer and no/false/0 returns only questions with no positively-scored answers.

You can have a function accept a string as input and return an `int`.

---

One can use an [information retrieval tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (***trie*** data structure) for the following strings:

- "no"
- "false"
- "yes"
- "true"

The behavior should be case-insensitive.

---

For any two strings ***w*** and ***w′*** if ***w**** is valid input and ***w***(0) = ***w′***(0) and ***w′*** is a sub-sequence of ***w***, then ***w′*** is also valid input.

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| "yes" | 1 |
| "Y" | 1 |
| "y" | 1 |
| "Ye" | 1 |
| "Ys" | 1 |
| "N" | 0 |
| "n" | 0 |
| "No" | 0 |
| "F" | 0 |
| "false" | 0 |
| "FLS" | 0 |

Comment: How is "answers:no" currently interpreted?

Comment: @Joachim It seems to be ignored completely. `is:q answers:anyNonNumericValue` returns the same number of results as `is:q`.